# Cancelling member deletion in member_delete hook handler

Tags: hook, delete

I am trying to implement some codein the `member_delete` hook in EE. But for testing purposes, I just want the hook to trigger but don't go ahead with the actual delete.

Is there a way to do this? In some other form related extension hooks, I only need to set the error variables to be able to cancel submit. I am not sure if the same can be said of `member_delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - just make sure you return `NULL` or an empty array at the end of your method. (The hook expects an array of `member_id`s to be sent back.)

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful information when developing future hooks.