# member_delete hook isn't deleting member after my code

Tags: members, hook

I've got an extension that is using the member_delete hook which checks a specific entry field for the deleted member's ID and removes it if found.

This is working fine (field cleared of member ID) and I am shown the EE message saying that the member has been deleted however when I view the member list the member still remains.

I read question [Cancelling member deletion in member_delete hook handler](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12127/cancelling-member-deletion-in-member-delete-hook-handler) and it says that you need to return an array of member_ids for it to continue. I've done just that but it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Here is my code:

```
function del_client_check($member_ids) {
    $cleared_entries = array();

    $member_id = $member_ids[0];

    $field['m_client'] = $this->settings['client_field'];
    $field['e_client'] = $this->settings['e_client_field'];
    $m_field = $this->settings['member_field'];

    $this->EE->db->select('entry_id, ' . $m_field . '');
    $entries = $this->EE->db->get('channel_data')->result_array();

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry[$m_field] != '') {
            $members = explode('|', $entry[$m_field]);

            if (($key = array_search($member_id, $members)) !== false) {
                unset($members[$key]);

                $entry[$m_field] = implode('|', $members);
                $cleared_entries[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($cleared_entries)) {
        $this->entry_update_del($cleared_entries, $member_id);
    } else {
        return $member_ids;
    }
}

function entry_update_del($entries, $member_id) {
    $member_ids = array();
    $this->EE->db->update_batch('channel_data', $entries, 'entry_id');
    $member_ids[0] = $member_id;
    return $member_ids;
}
```

*Just a note, in the entry_update_del function I am setting `$member_ids[0]` to `$member_id`. There is always only going to be 1 member deleted at a time.*

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take *return* statement out of *} else {*.

You should always return member_ids that should be deleted.

So, change

```
if (!empty($cleared_entries)) {
    $this->entry_update_del($cleared_entries, $member_id);
} else {
    return $member_ids;
}
```

to

```
if (!empty($cleared_entries)) {
    $this->entry_update_del($cleared_entries, $member_id);
} 
return $member_ids;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for that. I understand why it didn't work now.